# Out of memory when refactoring a method

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I had some out of memory issue in my code, right after I refactored a method, to something more generic, that I can call it with my parameters.
The method prior to the change, responded immediately, even though it is reading thousands of rows, while the refactored method, ran out of memory and seemed heavy.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> MapFile(string[] fileRows)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var row in fileRows)
        {
            var key = row.Substring(3, 10) + row.Substring(45, 11);
            dic[key] = row;
        }
        return dic;
    }
```

The rafactored method:

```
        private Dictionary<string, string> MapFile(string[] fileRows, params KeyValuePair<int, int>[] keyIndexes)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        StringBuilder keyPair = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var row in fileRows)
        {
            foreach (var keyIndex in keyIndexes)
            {
                keyPair.Append(row.Substring(keyIndex.Key, keyIndex.Value));
            }
            dic[keyPair.ToString()] = row;
        }
        return dic;
    }
```

Calling it like:

```
 MapFile(file, new KeyValuePair<int,int>(3,10), new KeyValuePair<int,int>(45,11))
```

I understand the code need to do some more work, but still don't understand the huge difference between reading those two methods. one is smooth and response in less than a second, the other take all of the system's memory, and crash.

Upate:

Wanted to know, if this implementation, using Tuple as the type to store a pair of int, used with the Substring inside the method (index, length) is smarter and a better practice ?

```
private Dictionary<string, string> MapFile(string[] fileRows, params Tuple<int, int>[] keyIndexes)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var row in fileRows)
        {
            string key = "";
            foreach (var pair in keyIndexes)
            {
                key += row.Substring(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
            }
            dic[key] = row;
        }
        return dic;
    }
```

Comment: dont you want keyPair inside the loop, your key keeps growing forever

Comment: is keyIndex.Value itself a dictionary that might inflate the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that you are appending 2 values to the StringBuilder on every single row, so in each loop you are making the StringBuilder store larger values, up until you run out of memory

What you should do, instead, so that the logic doesn't change from the previous version, is this:

```
foreach (var row in fileRows)
{
     StringBuilder keyPair = new StringBuilder(); // Create a new instance each time
     foreach (var keyIndex in keyIndexes)
     {
         keyPair.Append(row.Substring(keyIndex.Key, keyIndex.Value));
     }
     dic[keyPair.ToString()] = row;
 }
```

If you want to use only one instance of the StringBuilder though, you can do this:

```
StringBuilder keyPair = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var row in fileRows)
{
     foreach (var keyIndex in keyIndexes)
     {
         keyPair.Append(row.Substring(keyIndex.Key, keyIndex.Value));
     }
     dic[keyPair.ToString()] = row;
     keyPair.Clear(); // ensure it is cleared for the next row
 }
```

Yet another thing you could be doing is this, so that you don't have to deal with StringBuilder's:

```
foreach (var row in fileRows)
{
     string key = string.Empty;
     foreach (var keyIndex in keyIndexes)
     {
         key += row.Substring(keyIndex.Key, keyIndex.Value);
     }
     dic[key] = row;
 }
```

Comment: OP seem to try reusing the `StringBuilder` instance. So moving it inside the outer `foreach` is not strongly necessary - adding `keyPair.Clear();` would be quite enough.

Comment: @IvanStoev I thought of that, but the method ends right there. I'll add it as another solution

Comment: Of course, better still would be the original code that the OP started with, as it'd be notably more efficient than either of these options.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Embarrassing to see how stupid that was.. I'm working too many hours :)

Comment: @Servy for sure, but the OP seems to want to use the StringBuilder for some reason.

Comment: @RoniAxelrad You are welcome. By the way, you could have just passed through parameters the indexes and leave all the rest as it was

Comment: Why would the first option is the best for your opinion, and, do you think a string instead of stringbuilder would be better here? I mean, If i need to call that mapping method with different index cuts everytime, wouldn't it be a good idea to "generate" it, like i'm trying to ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The OP is trying to refactor the code to improve it without changing the behavior.  You're suggesting changes that make it worse.  If you're going to propose a change, propose the one that'll do the best, namely the OP's original code.

Comment: @RoniAxelrad Why would you think that creating a new object and using a tool that's not designed for this exact operation would work *better* than using the exact tool that's specifically designed to do the exact operation that you need to do?

Comment: @Servy but the OP does not want the original behavior. I believe he wants to have any amount of indexes (that's why the params). Also, how is my second method so different than the OP's original? I cannot see that

Comment: @Servy I'm trying to take a row, and find the uniqe key of it, which is built of different indexes inside the row, so this time the key was position 3, length 10 plus position 45, length 11, but next time it'll be 3 positions, or more.. and different length.. so I thought that building it as i can provide the positions will make it better

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The OP is looking to make refactors.  Refactors, *by definition* aren't changing behavior, so the original behavior *is* correct, so you're looking to make changes that *don't* change the behavior of the code, but still improve it in some way.  Your example is slower and uses more memory, gaining nothing in return.

Comment: @Servy But that's only that the OP is using the wrong term. He wants to refactor to allow more, dynamic indexes (as per the last comment)

Comment: @RoniAxelrad Storing the indexes somewhere where they can be more effectively managed doesn't inhibit your ability to use string concatenation.

Comment: @Servy, That's a good Idea :) The intention of the code was just a little tool to help me, and I didn't expect to put a lot of effort in it, but storing the indexes "outside" and using them make sense.. I'll try to do it..

Answer (score 2):

```
    StringBuilder keyPair = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var row in fileRows)
    {
        foreach (var keyIndex in keyIndexes)
        {
            keyPair.Append(row.Substring(keyIndex.Key, keyIndex.Value));
        }
        dic[keyPair.ToString()] = row;
    }
```

Here's a question for you...  what is keyPair.ToString() going to evaluate to here?

Answer: A concatenation of everything you've appended.  It will grow for every time through the loop.  Eventually, keyPair will be a huge string that you are using as a key to your dictionary.

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but try moving the StringBuilder creation INSIDE the first foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That was right, like Camilo mentioned, Just wanted your opinion, why do you think the code doesn't make sense?

Comment: Yeah, Camilo ninja'd me on this one.

Comment: I don't understand what "keyPair" is, or what Substring(keyIndex.Key, keyIndex.Value) is getting you...  a substring that starts with the key and has length equal to the value seems like a weird and hard to understand way of using a KeyValuePair.

Comment: Is this intended to be a sort of hash algorithm?  Reducing lines of data to a few substrings within the line?  I'm sure you have your reasons, but I don't understand the use case.  (You don't necessarily need to explain it to me - only if you think it'll help.)  :)

Comment: I just needed a method that maps the line I read everytime using diffrent keys, this time the key was 2 parts of the line, but some other times, it'll be other parts, so instead of calling the same method with different positions everytime, i thought to make it generic, but I agree with the key-value pair, just didn't have a better solution for a pair of ints

Comment: The use case, was in general, comparing two very big files, on each file, I read the lines, creating a map of unique key to this line, then finding this key in the other file, and comparing the lines. They key to map each line, is located in each row, for one file the position X1 length Y1 + X2 length Y2, and the other file is H1, L1, G1 + .. the point is that the keys to compare the lines appears in different indexes, So instead of calling the same code again and again, I wanted a method which i can provide what is the key positions.. Hope I was clear enough :)